# Flink kafka consumer group.id not works

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api, group

I use apache fink with FlinkKafkaConsumer, I have 2 consumer read 1 topic(1partition). At one time, both consumers read the same event. I expect consumer1 receive event1, consumer2 can not receive event1. I used group.id but it not works. I refer to Flink's document, group.id is not support this.

Example: topic (e1,e2,e3,e4,e5)

result :

consumer 1: e1,e2,e3,e4,e5

consumer 2: e1,e2,e3,e4,e5

expect:

consumer1 : e1,e3

consumer2: e2,e4,e5

This is my code

```
String kafkaBootstrapServers = config.get(SOURCE_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
String kafkaGroupId = config.get(SOURCE_KAFKA_GROUPID);
String topic = config.get(SOURCE_KAFKA_TOPIC);

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServers);
properties.setProperty("group.id", kafkaGroupId);

properties.setProperty("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
properties.setProperty("sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-512");
properties.setProperty("ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "");
properties.setProperty("ssl.truststore.location", config.get(SOURCE_KAFKA_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION));
properties.setProperty("ssl.truststore.password", config.get(SOURCE_KAFKA_TRUSTSTORE_PASS));
properties.put("sasl.jaas.config",
       String.format("org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"kafkascram\" password=\"%s\";", config.get(SOURCE_KAFKA_TRUSTSTORE_PASS)));

FlinkKafkaConsumer<EventBase> kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(topic, new SimpleSyslogEventSchema(), properties);
kafkaConsumer.setStartFromGroupOffsets();
return kafkaConsumer;
```

Comment: How did you determine that you were getting duplicated events in Flink (versus there being duplicated events in the topic)?

Comment: I check events in kafka UI and log events in two consumer flink. a both consumer receive same events

Answer (score 1):

The `FlinkKafkaConsumer` was [deprecated in Flink 1.14](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/release-notes/flink-1.14/#deprecate-flinkkafkaconsumer) and replaced with the newer [`KafkaSource`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#kafka-source) API, which you'd likely want to use instead of the older, deprecated API. A similar implementation of the same consumer would look something like this:

```
KafkaSource.builder<EventBase>()
    .setBootstrapServers(kafkaBootstrapServers)
    .setTopics(topic)
    .setGroupId(kafkaGroupId)
    .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
    .setValueOnlyDeserializer(SimpleSyslogEventSchema())
    // Add your SASL Configuration here
    .setProperty("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
    .setProperty("sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-512") 
    .setProperty("ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "")
    .setProperty("ssl.truststore.location", config.get(SOURCE_KAFKA_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION)). 
    .setProperty("ssl.truststore.password", config.get(SOURCE_KAFKA_TRUSTSTORE_PASS))
    .setProperty("sasl.jaas.config", String.format("org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"kafkascram\" password=\"%s\";", config.get(SOURCE_KAFKA_TRUSTSTORE_PASS)));
    .build();
```

Configuration-wise, your existing `group.id` looks correct for the older `FlinkKafkaConsumer` API, however it's important to note that the value for this *must* be the same (preferably some constant for the job) to ensure that the consumer-group offsets are shared as you would expect.

Comment: I try it but, it is not work as expectation.

Comment: What is your `group.id` set to? All of the previously mentioned configuration should work as expected. Have you checked the consumer-group offsets to see what they look like if they are being committed? Any additional information on your job graph could be useful as well, but configuration-wise, `group.id` should be all you need.

Comment: You should see something in your Flink logs to indicate that specific `group.id` is being used for your consumer along with the offsets/partitions it’s reading from.

Comment: Have you enabled checkpointing?